# How do we know the ground potential is higher than the potential at the non-inverting terminal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: Picture of circuit]

I'm just curious why it's -IB2 * R3 not IB2 * R3.
The IB2 is the non-inverting and IB1 is the inverting side.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know.  It is just the sign convention that inputs are treated as current sinks.  If they actually source current, the current will be specified as negative.  There are BJT opamp input stages of either kind as well as current-compensated inputs that will average out to zero by having the bias current applied by on-device circuitry.